# Android trigger onConfigurationChanged after views are redrawn

Tags: android, webview, screen-rotation

I have an activity with custom rotation handling with a WebView.
The problem is that I need to trigger an event **after** the layout is redrawn due to the orientation change. In my rotation handler, I'm detecting elements wider than the webview. When triggering this handler in onConfigurationChanged, view size is not recalculated yet so I'm getting width before rotation.

I have two bad solutions:

- calculate the size programatically from the other sceen dimension and all paddings and other views, but it is too complicated and ineffective.
- trigger the handler with some timeout, but it is ugly with long timeout and not reliable with short timeout.

Is there some event triggered after the layout is redrawn?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `View.onAttachedToWindow()`?

If that does not work (the documentation says it might even be called before `onMeasure()`, so I'm not sure whether the timing and freuqency suit your needs), you could maybe hook into the layout process, by extending one of the View objects you use, and override `View.onLayout` to schedule a UI thread callback. I would prepare for a multiple occurence though.

Comment: Actually, onLayout turned out to be the correct solution. Thanks

Comment: @user1660584 Glad I could help. Spent a bit of time sub-classing Views recently. ;)